# InDesign is changing the color of my image when I export!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, color, export, jpg

I have been exporting JPEG in InDesign, my settings are good (I think), but when I export it and open it, the color is darker. What am I doing wrong? I also have the same problem when I export jpeg in photoshop. Left one is the original, right one is the one exported from InDesign. [image]

My settings:
[image]

Comment: InDesign works in CMYK color, I'm guessing this is what is causing your jpg image to appear less vibrant.  Even though you are exporting as an RGB jpg, the source of that image is still CMYK.

Answer (score 1):

John should be correct if you are exporting as CMYK, look up "Color Gamut" online and you can see the difference between RGB and CMYK color models.  You might want to check to see if the box you have the picture imported into in inDesign has a very light fill applied, as well.  Often that will shade a picture when exported if not turned to "none".  We get this sometimes when we give out templates with picture boxes set to a very light fill to indicate placeholders; and then the clients drop the photos in, but don't set the fill to "none".  Creates a weird duotone-like effect.

Kurt